# Vue props that aren't explicitly declared

Tags: javascript, frontend, vuejs2, vue.js

I am making an attempt at something similar to `redux-form` but in Vue & with Vuex. Basically it should make the handling of forms more streamlined and make you write less boilerplate.

The problem i'm having is when i'm trying to pass props dynamically to a component from a HOC. I'm not quite sure how to do it. In React you would simply do something like this:

```
<VfField unknownPropA="abc" unknownPropB="123" name="test" />
```

And in VfField.js:

```
export default ({name, ...props}) => <div name={name}><InputComponent {...props} /></div>
```

This would result in `props` being an object containing `unknownPropA` and `unknownPropB`.

But in Vue I have some code that looks like this:

```
<vf-form @submit="submit" @validate="validate">
  <vf-field type="text" name="username" unknownPropA="abc"></vf-field>
  <vf-field type="password" name="password" unknownPropB="123"></vf-field>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</vf-form>
```

So how can `vf-field` then access these "unknown" props and pass them to their child component? `$vm.$props` simply yields the props i explicitly declared, but completely disregards the other(`unknownPropA` and `unknownPropB`). The power to "dynamically" pass props is what i'm looking for since it's really useful in many cases.

**Note:**

So far i think Vue is great for simple things and it's way faster to get something up and running than it would be in, say, React. But as soon as something is "out of the ordinary", so far, i find that React is more helpful. This may, of course, be due to my lack of knowledge in Vue.

Comment: I don't think there is a standard way to get undeclared properties, you could write your own method that parses `this.$el.attributes` as a mixin, but the other idea I had was what @Saurabh suggested in his answer and it's safer and better.

Comment: The props in template should be written in kebab-case style `unknow-prop-b` and you register it as `props: ['unknownPropB']` in your component that accept them

Comment: I think that saying it's better or not is a matter of taste to be honest. For me, writing this as a third part library, i think it's better for my users to be able to specify their props directly on the vf-field instead of specifying them in via a "dumb" prop. Passing attributes won't work for me since users need to be able to pass more than just strings.

Comment: Sorry but i didn't get this "Passing attributes won't work for me since users need to be able to pass more than just strings" - you can pass any type of data via props.

Comment: Yeah, just a matter of `JSON.parse`

Comment: By creating a method that parses this.$el.attributes i would lose the ability to pass anything other than strings. Assuming that $el.attributes are the actual DOM attributes?

Comment: And overhead that i don't want. Also i still cannot pass anything complex, only things that can be serialized to JSON.

Comment: complex like? almost everything can be serialized to JSON.

Comment: @Saurahb like functions, symbols, classes. Only the most primitive things can be serialized via JSON.steingify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is tricky and certainly not supported natively, however you can get the passed attributes from `vnode` using `this.$vnode.elm.attributes` and then loop through them and add them to a props object (which does need to be declared upfront). Because you will be processing this yourself I would put this in a `mixin` so it can be reused, but you can do:

```
  methods: {
    getProps() {
      let props = this.$vnode.elm.attributes;
      Object.keys(props).forEach(key => {
        this.$set(this.props, props[key].name, props[key].nodeValue)
      });
    }
  },
  data(){
    return{
      props: {}
    }
  }
```

With this you can then pass unknown props as if you declared them in your component.

I've made a JSFiddle to show you the process: https://jsfiddle.net/2c23Lb5t/

Here's how you would do this with a `mixin`: https://jsfiddle.net/fej7wu5f/

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `$attrs` to get anything that isn't recognized as a prop: [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-attrs). Note that the opposite also exists: you can get all the props with `$props`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead you can pass an object to child as props, and it can have all the properties you want.

It can be like:

```
<VfField :unknownPropObj=yourObj name="test" />
```

Where `yourObj` can be: `{"A": "abc", "B": "123"}`

So you can define only on prop: `unknownPropObj` in the child, and access all it's properties

Comment: Yes, but i would like to avoid this. It feels more natural to pass e.g. a "label" prop to the field itself like so: <vf-field label='Username' type='text'></vf-field> than passing it like <vf-field :props='someProps' type='text'></vf-field>. The first example is both easier to code(less code) and it's easier to see what actually gets passed just by looking at the vf-field.

Comment: @OscarLinde Well you are correct in saying that first one seems better, but unfortunately I dont see any such support in vue docs, as I think it is need to declare them to make them reactive.

Comment: Indeed :( I tried to look in docs as well as in source but couldn't find any way to do it. If passing my props in another prop is the only way i'll have to do it that way, but i am very reluctant. API is king, and i do believe this is a feature to be considered if we're right in that it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with **v-bind="$attrs"**

```
<VfField v-bind="$attrs" name="test" />
```

You may pass the option **inheritAttrs: false** to the child component if you want to manually decide which element will receive the attributes (by default the root element inherits them).

```
<script>
  export default {
    inheritAttrs: false,
  };
</script>
```

Reference: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Disabling-Attribute-Inheritance